# Fetch Rick and Morty API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I try to fetch Rick and Morty API (https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character). I try to attach a single character after his id along with the details about it (name, gender, status, species etc). But I don't know, I just managed to display them all. How do I set the id to display information about a character based on the id. When I click on a character, the details are displayed on the Info page. This si my snippet code:

```
function App() {

const [items, setItems] = useState([])
const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const [query, setQuery]=useState('')
const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
const [id, setId] = useState(1)

useEffect(() => {
const fetchItems = async () => {
  const result = await axios(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=${page}&?name=${query}$id=${id}`)
  
 
  console.log("Character:", result.data.results)

  setItems(result.data.results)
  setInfo(result.data.info)
  setIsLoading(false)
}

 fetchItems()
}, [query, page, id])

const nextHandler = (event) => {
event.preventDefault()
if(page <= info.pages) {
  setPage(page + 1)
}else {
  setPage(1)
}}

const prevHandler = (event) => {
event.preventDefault()
if(page>1){
  setPage(page - 1)
}else{
  setPage(page)
}}

return (
<div className='container'>
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' >
      <Header />
      <Search getQuery={(q) =>setQuery(q) } />
      <div className='pagination'>

      <button className='btn-prev'
      onClick={(event) => prevHandler(event)}
      >
        Prev
      </button>
      <p className='number'>{page}/{info.pages}</p>
      <button className='btn-next'
      onClick={(event) => nextHandler(event)}
      >
       Next
      </button>
      </div>
      <Character isLoading={isLoading} items={items} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/info'>
      <Header />
      <Info items={items} id={id}/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
</div>
)}
```

Character:

```
const Character = ({ items, isLoading }) => {
return isLoading ? (
<Spinner />
) : (
<div>

<section className='cards'>
  {items.map((item) => (
      <CharacterItem key={item.id} item={item}></CharacterItem>
      ))}
</section>

</div>
)}
```

CharacterItem:

```
const CharacterItem = ({ item }) => {

return (
<div className="card">
    <div className="card-header">
        <img src={item.image} alt='img' />
    </div>
    <div className="card-body">
        <h4>
            Name: {item.name}
        </h4>
        <p>
            Status:  {item.status}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
)}
```

Info:

```
const Info = () => {

const [items, setItems] = useState([])
const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
const [id, setId] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const result = await axios(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?id=${id}`)
  
      setItems(result.data.results)
      setInfo(result.data.info)
    }
    fetchItems()
  }, [id])

return (
    <div>
    
<div className="card-info">
    <div className="card-header-info">
    {/* <img src={props.image} alt='img' /> */}
    </div>
    <div className="card-body-info">
        <h4>
            Name: {items.name} or {name} or ?
        </h4>
        <p>
            Gender: {items.gender} or {gender} or ?
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to fetch specific id, by /id.

```
const result = await axios(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${id}`)
```

Comment: And setId? To change when i click on the character?

Comment: you should have a character with id mapped to it, then pass or set that id when you click on any character.